# How do I slice an path string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey guys I'm using an input for select an file
`<input type="file">`, and I want to get the file name.
I'm using jquery to get the fakepath, like this `C:\fakepath\fasfw.jpg`.

How do I slice that string to get just the file name? I've been trying to slice using

```
.split('\');
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: you have to escape `\` with 2 of them

Comment: @DanielA.White your comment is so ironic

Comment: @PatrickRoberts one of the limitations of markdown...

Comment: Why don't you use, `var files = event.target.files;` 
 `var fileName = files[0].name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `<input type="file">`, there's an easier way to get the filename, using the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) property from the list of [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects returned by the [`files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Additional_attributes) attribute of the input element:

```js
document.querySelector('[type=file]').addEventListener('change', function () {
  const [file] = this.files
  
  if (file) {
    console.log(file.name)
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="file">
```